# Select "div class" from ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I´ve the following ajax-response which is generated by my server-sided script:

```
<div class="item-title3">Testname</div>
<div class="item-level">120</div>
<div class="item-binding">40</div>
<div class="item-type">Feet</div>
```

Now I want to find the content of the `<div class="item-title3">` ("Testname" in that case) and use it as a link name.

Therefore I turned the ajax data into a jQuery object to select certain elements from it. Sadly it still can´t find it.

**Complete code:**

```
<script language="javascript">

jQuery(function($) {
  
  $("[tooltip-link]").each(function() {
    let $tooltip = $(this);
    let id = $tooltip.attr("data-id");

    $.ajax({ 
      url: "/datenbank/itemscript.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        "var": id
      }
    }).then(function(data) {
      let $content = $(data);
      let title = $content.find('.item-title3').text()

      $tooltip.tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "test",
        content: data
      });

       $("<div class=\"item-title\">Item-" + title + "</div>").appendTo($tooltip);
    });
  });
    
});
</script>

<a tooltip-link data-id="12555" title=""></a>
```

Comment: Hi, try like this : `$content.siblings('.item-title3').text()`